# Can't print from OS X 10.7 to shared printer on OS X 10.6

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, sharing, printing

I have a network with 2 Mac OS X computers in it.

When I try to print a text document from my upgraded OS X 10.7 to the shared printer on OS X 10.6, my print job gets stuck at the "job pending on server" message.

When I look at the printer spooler on the 10.6 machine, I see the job as "printing" and the message "sending data", but the printer doesn't print anything. There's no reaction at all, and yes – I checked the cables.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the Problem. The shared Printer was connected to a [Belkin USB](http://www.belkin.com/IWCatProductPage.process?Product_Id=357387) Hub, which again was connected through an USB slot to the Mac OS 10.6 Laptop. I disconnected the printer from the Hub and plugged it straight into the usb slot of the laptop, when I tried again print out a document, it succeeded